# How to visit a private host behind a router?

Tags: linux, git, networking, ssh

I saw someone did this: he could ssh login to or git clone from his private host behind a router home, on a publicly accessible VPS.
How did he achieve that, visiting a private host from outside?

Comment: He probably had a port open and ssh tunneled through it or he was connected via a VPN. FYI, this question is likely off-topic for SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [create an ssh tunnel](https://superuser.com/a/277220/50508). Or you can use logmein hamachi to create a VPN between remote hosts.

Answer (score 0):

Use Port Forwarding. See the wikipedia article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding